# jQuery get background-color from two clicked divs and then compare them

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, click

So I'm trying to make a memory game and the project is going forward slow but steady.

I have a 4x4 layout of divs with class "card" and pair-unique colors. I'm trying to make something along these lines:

Click one div, get color, save to pick1.
Click another div, get color, save to pick2.
Compare the two.

For now im not even comparing, but simply alerting the variables pick1 and 2 to see what I get from clicking.

I've tried some different ways of retrieving the background-color from the divs and for now I'm using the following:

```
$('.card').click(function(){
    pick1 = $(this).css('background-color');    
});

$('.card').click(function(){
    pick2 = $(this).css('background-color');
});


alert(pick1 + " and " + pick2);
```

But it just alerts straight away and shows the divs afterwards. If I make it run this part twice it simply alerts twice instead, and then shows the divs.

How do I make it let me click before alerting? I'm new to jQuery since yesterday and haven't used javascript at all for two years :p

here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/94jerdaw/WJQkA/

Also, is there a better way of comparing the divs instead of background-color? It's in rgb format, if that's even possible to compare as it is?

Comment: never delete your original question content, after getting your answer. SO is meant for everybody to get benefited from others problem. so avoid it in future also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it with just one click event. And it's enough to just compare the two rgb strings.

```js
var pick1 = false;
var pick2 = false;

$('.card').click(function(){

    if(pick1) {
        pick2 = $(this).css('background-color');
        if(pick1 == pick2) alert('Correct');
        else alert('Incorrect');

        pick1 = false;
        pick2 = false;
    } else {
        pick1 = $(this).css('background-color');   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all

> How do I make it let me click before alerting?

for this to work you need to call alert inside the click event....since you are calling alert on document.ready.. alert gets called first(as soon as document gets ready)..

secondly , you are calling the click function twice for same selector `.card` which is not good at all....

the way around to get what you want is .. creating an array and on click push the background color or respective div to that array and compare values in that array..

```
var tempArray=[]; //create an array
$('.card').click(function(){
    alert($(this).css('background-color')) //this will give you alert after click with the bgcolor
    tempArray.push($(this).css('background-color'));
    console.log(tempArray) //check you developers tool > console to check the array.
});
```

now you have all the clicked bgcolor inside tempArray, you can now do your comparing stuff.. since i hav no idea what you are trying to do(compare) so i think this will get you started.

**updated**

similar as above but with comparision logic...used inArray and clickedCount...check it out

```
 var tempArray=[]; //create an array
 var clickedCount= 1;
$('.card').click(function(){
  var bgColor=$(this).css('background-color') ;

  if(tempArray.length > 0){
     if(($.inArray(bgColor, tempArray)) != -1){
       alert("correct");
     }else{
       alert("incorrect");
     }
  }
    if(clickedCount % 2 != 0){  
       tempArray.push($(this).css('background-color'));
    }else{
       tempArray=[];
    }
     clickedCount++;
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/WJQkA/1/)

[updated working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WJQkA/5/)

Comment: I'm simply trying to compare the two clicked divs' colors and make out an correct or incorrect guess from it.

Comment: but since you are comapring the color of two seperate cliked div's with its color... the guess will always be incorrect.. i think...to get the correct guess, user just have to click the same div twice so the color matches... are you getting me???

Comment: All divs are in pairs colorwise...   are you getting me???

if not, just check the fiddle :)

Comment: ok.. my bad...got you this time...and here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WJQkA/5/

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that after the second pick... both values get reset. So this is what I would do:

```
var pick1 = null;
var pick2 = null;

$('.card').click(function() {

    // set first card
    if (pick1 === null) {

        pick1 = $(this).css('background-color');

    }
    // set second card
    else if (pick2 === null) {

        pick2 = $(this).css('background-color');

        // compare colors
        if (pick1 === pick2) {
            alert('MATCH!');
        }
        else alert('NO MATCH!');

        // reset pick variables
        pick1 = null;
        pick2 = null;
    }

});
```

This could be shorter but I've elaborated to make it more obvious what's happening.